# Hidden nav bar on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to have a navigation menu for an education website similar in structure to the one found [here](http://ccscougars.org/academics/high-school).

Take note of the left-hand navigation menu header and list items. In desktop view, all nav items appear, but in mobile view, only the header is visible (and you have to click the + icon to have the nav menu items appear)

Looking at the elements it appears there's some javascript working in the background that switches the CSS class names when the site goes to mobile view.

I've been trying to recreate something similar to no avail...

Could someone please take a stab at it using a simple structure like this using JSFiddle?

Nav Title (on click, Nav Menu Items 1-3 appears/disappears below)

- Menu Link 1
- Menu Link 2
- Menu Link 3

I'd really appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: looks like it's using a js library found here: https://www.twinhelix.com/dhtml/fsmenu/

Answer (score 0):

there are already existing bootstrap templates and plugin that meet your requirement. Also you can leverage android material design guide line & sample templates.

1. https://getmdl.io/
   (Edit: Copied from OP's comments:)
   ... is the design guideline from google for making web-apps. The idea is to make consistent looking as native possible. the site includes components like icons, widgets, navbar etc. Also contains sample templates that can be clone or download from git.
2. http://getbootstrap.com/
   Bootstrap on the other hand have same features but its more targeted mobile first design approach.

Again if you want both you can check out [materializecss.com](http://materializecss.com)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the content of the linked sites?

Comment: getmdl -> It is the design guideline from google for making web-apps. The idea is to make consistent looking as native possible. the site includes components like icons, widgets, navbar etc. Also contains sample templates that can be clone or download from git. And Bootstrap on the other hand have same features but its more targeted mobile first design approach. Both are equally as good. Again if you want both you can check out http://materializecss.com/